# UITableView using selectRowAtIndexPath in cellForRow causes double highlight

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

**Background:** I am trying to implement a sectioned tableview that can collapse and expand. When collapsed, the table will remember what was selected and preserve the selected state when expanded.

**Problem:** The a section expanded and function like it should. The cell was selected like it should. However, the cell in the same place but next section appeared to be highlighted as well.

**Example:** I have 2 sections: *A* and *B*. In each section I have 3 cells: *a*, *b* and *c*. I expand both sections so all the cells are displayed on the screen and nothing is selected. I then tap on (*A*, *a*). The cell (*A*, *a*) is highlighted and all is well. I collapsed section *A*, then expand section *A*. (*A*, *a*) is highlighted as it should. However, (*B*, *a*) is also highlighted as well. This can be repeated with (*A*, *b*) and (*A*, *c*). It would light up (*B*, *b*) and (*B*, *c*) respectively.

**Project:** <*Removed*>

**Code:**

`viewController.m`  holds detail matter to this.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    UITableView * _tableView;

    BOOL aOpen;
    BOOL bOpen;
    BOOL cOpen;

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View stuff
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [[TableViewHeader alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) title:@"Section A" section:section isOpen:aOpen delegate:self];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [[TableViewHeader alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) title:@"Section B" section:section isOpen:bOpen delegate:self];
            break;
        case 2:
            return [[TableViewHeader alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) title:@"Section C" section:section isOpen:cOpen delegate:self];
            break;
        default:
            return Nil;
            break;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 40;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return aOpen? 3:0;
            break;
        case 1:
            return bOpen? 4:0;
            break;
        case 2:
            return cOpen? 5:0;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }

}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.contentView.alpha = .4;
    }

    if ([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {//if it was already selected
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 74;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;

}

//for high visibility purpose
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 2) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        return view;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - header delegate handler
- (void) headerTappedAtSection: (int) section {
    BOOL openAction = false;
    int numberOfRow;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            aOpen = !aOpen;
            openAction = aOpen;
            numberOfRow = 3;
            break;
        case 1:
            bOpen = !bOpen;
            openAction = bOpen;
            numberOfRow = 4;
            break;
        case 2:
            cOpen = !cOpen;
            openAction = cOpen;
            numberOfRow = 5;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [_tableView reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    if (openAction && numberOfRow) {
        [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Your sample project's link is broken.

Comment: @JesseBunch Thank you, it is fixed now.

Comment: Probably, it's because selectedIndexPath is not retained. Have you tried selectedIndexPath = [indexPath copy]? (You would have to then release the object too). Maybe you can use NSLog in if condition to check the value of selectedIndexPath.

Comment: @BumbleBoks thank you, I did look into it and everything works correctly. I am using ARC thus retaining and release is not applicable. In my real project, I used a specific `int` id. So nothing to release or retain. Please refer to my sample project, it has everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing the following:

Remove from tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {//if it was already selected
     [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

And add inside header delegate handler function after reloadSection (maybe in if (openAction && numberOfRow){})

```
     [_tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

This will make sure that cell is selected after the section is reloaded. And since selectedCellIndex is saved, you should be able to use it to select the cell.

Comment: This works! However, I also would like an explanation on why my approach falls short. I will +1 you. Unless no one else is able to provide the reason, I will mark your answer correct.

Comment: I am guessing here. I think that cell selection gets associated with the index path and the row on the table where it will appear after the section is reloaded. So, before section get reloaded if the selected row is 3, it gets associated with the index path of row 3 in section A, (which will appear as 3rd row)

Comment: I am guessing here. I think that cell selection gets associated with the index path and the row (say 3) on the table where it will appear after the section is done reloading. But when cellforRow... is called, the row that is actually at that place on the table on screen is row 3 of sectionB (because sectionA has not appeared yet). So row 3 of sectionB is marked as selected. Now when section A appears, row 3 is marked selected as well (since the index path for the row is marked as selected). As I said this is my best guess. I too would like to know the actual reason.

Comment: This is a very logical reason. However, if it were to be so, the selection should still showed highlighted only the unintentional cell. But the selection was called only once while 2 cells are highlighted.

Comment: Ok some more guesswork :).  
I have to think cell selection in tableView is linked to the index path of the selected cell (given that there is indexPathsForSelectedRows method to get index paths). Since only section A is reloaded, selectRow… is called only once for the row selected in section A .  But selectRow.. would also color the corresponding cell on the table on screen, which at the moment of selection is cell for the same row in section B (section A hasn't appeared on screen yet). When section A is inserted, entire section B just moves down (along with the color to indicate selection).

Comment: So  row in section B would appear as selected even though it is not selected; indexPathsForSelectedRows would give only the index path for the selected row in section A and not the one in section B. I would say the behavior would be more predictable if the table section is reloaded before making a selection.

Comment: I highly doubt it. Here is why: `NSIndexPath` consists of Section and Row. Let's say (A, a) is not available, selecting (A, a) would return nothing. What you are suggesting is that, if (A, a) does not exist, it would automatically select (B, a). Please play around with my sample project. You can test out the theories, I spent hours on it to find out why, but cannot come to a conclusion :(

Comment: That's the best answer I could think of. That said, I still think it's better to reload the table section completely before using selectRowAtIndexPath.. I am sorry, it won't be possible for me to play around with your sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Does your table view have `allowsMultipleSelection` set to `YES`? If so, you need to set that to `NO` so that the table view will *replace* the section rather than add to it when you call `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sadly it is not that simple. I have not set `allowsMultipleSelection` to `YES`. I did however, tried to explicitly set it to `NO`. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
[_tableView reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

with a simple..

```
 [_tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: What he is doing is right, he is reloading the particular section instead of whole table, there is no need of reloading the whole table though.

Comment: @sreecharan is correct. `reloadData` is neither efficient nor pretty :)

Comment: For the sake of argument, **1.)** does solve the problem but without animation (not pretty and not intuitive). **2.)** 20 rows? You cannot assume that. Yes the *sample* project has 12 rows. The real thing can have unlimited number of rows as it is dynamically defined. **3.)** reloading 2 rows in one section is definitely more efficient than reloading 100 rows in 10 sections. Thank you for your input.

Comment: If this solves the problem, then maybe the issue is because of reuse of cells. Maybe you can try using different reuseIdentifiers for different sections.

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called for section B when section A is reloaded. So using different reuseIdentifiers should not make a difference.